# Does PHP's require() function cache its results in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, linux, filesystems, require

In a PHP script intended to work on generic shared LAMP hosting, I am using `require()` as a function to read data from a file. The data file looks like this:

```
<?php
# storage.php

return [
    // Rotating secrets
    'last_rand' => '532e89355b78aafdb85f5f01f0eed20440d6bd9e0a2d6ae1bd17be4e1d7d21c7bb7a822a2077e3f4',
];
```

And I read it like this:

```
$data = require($root . '/storage.php');
$lastRand = $data['last_rand'];
```

In my script, I will read information from a configuration file using this approach. In some cases, the operation will re-write a new config file (using `file_put_contents()`) and then re-read it, again using `require()`.

This has worked solidly so far, on a variety of LAMP hosts, but today I found a web host where the `require()` does not seem to notice changes in the file. This host is using PHP 5.6, whereas all the others I have tested are using 7+.

What's extremely odd is that `require()` gets the old contents of the file even though `file_get_contents()` can see the new version, as if `require()` is doing its own internal caching.

### Failed fix attempts

I have even tried waiting for `require()` to catch up, in case some underlying cache needed time to expire:

```
$ok = true;
$t = microtime(true);
while ($oldRandom != $this->getFileService()->requirePhp($this->getStoragePath())['last_rand'])
{
    $elapsedTime = microtime(true) - $t;
    if ($elapsedTime > 4) // Wait 4 seconds
    {
        $ok = false;
        break;
    }
    usleep(1000);
}
```

That did not work either (the timeout just expires with no change in the results brought back from `require()`).

However, upon the next run of the PHP script, `require()` suddenly sees the new file contents.

I've also tried to delete the `storage.php` file before re-reading it, and that has no effect either! I was really expecting that to help.

### Future actions

So, I don't understand this behaviour at all. To work around it I could:

- rather than modifying a new config, saving it to file and then reloading it from file, I could refactor my code so that I save the new config to memory, thus avoiding having to reload it
- refactor so that I use `file_get_contents()` rather than `require()` (for rather dull reasons it's not as convenient, but I'll prefer whatever works reliably).

However, these both feel like I am ignoring a bug, and that I should investigate the cause. I happen to know also that this host (a free one) is nearly always under heavy CPU load. It's a 64 bit server running Linux on the rather old 2.6 kernel, and `phpinfo()` indicates the CGI/FastCGI server API is in force.

Can anything be done to mitigate this behaviour?

### More attempts

Some helpful commenters suggest this problem could be related to opcaching, which seems to fit the general purpose of `require()`. I've added this code after the `file_put_contents()` that re-writes the config:

```
    $reset = opcache_reset(); // Returns true
    $invalid = opcache_invalidate($this->getStoragePath()); // Returns false
```

However, it makes no difference - `require()` stubbornly reads the same value. I have confirmed this by doing a `require()` before and after the file write, and also a `file_get_contents()` to get the true contents.

Comment: Have you considered `opcache` to be you POI?

Comment: No, I've not considered that @Alex - could you expand on that? For example, is there a command I can use to clear the op cache?

Comment: @halfer first check if there's any cache enabled with `phpinfo()`. Then you can use a cache-specific method to clear it. For `OPCache`, the actual method depends on the way you're running PHP. Take a look [here](https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-clear-php-opcache/)

Comment: @ishegg: thanks. I'm using CGI/FastCGI, have updated the post. I tried `opcache_reset()` but it made no difference - I assume that is coming back as `false`. I will continue this tomorrow - it's very late where I am `|-)`

Comment: My early tests are indicating that the reset command was returning as `true` and the invalidate on the storage file was returning as `false`, but neither helped. Unfortunately the one host exhibiting this problem has been unreachable for a while, so I will come back to this, perhaps later today. My inclination is now the problem is probably to do with the opcache, I don't feel bad about working around it (storing the new config in memory and serving it from there).

Comment: @ishegg: I've added a `phpinfo()` link (of dubious reliability!) in the comments above, and have updated the post. I will add an answer in a few minutes, but more info or answers are still welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I originally encountered this error, I was hesitant to work around it, since it felt like a critical bug that ought not be ignored. However, now that the culprit is likely to be opcaching (and thus related to `require()` specifically), I think working around it by keeping values in memory is not a bad solution. I shall have to remember that `require()` is only good for one call per HTTP request, even if that does not hold true for all PHP installations.

I am conscious also that if I did try to work around this, I would have to contend with a number of opcache invalidation mechanisms, which is more complexity than I am comfortable with.

Comment: I just got a look at your `phpinfo()` (I think you forgot to include it when you posted your comment), and you do have OPCache on. Try [`opcache_get_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php) to check if the `require()`d page is indeed in the cache.

Comment: Thanks @ishegg. Not sure what you mean about forgetting to post it - it's in my third comment under the question. I will delete it in due course, since the file will be removed in the future. Thanks for the additional info, I will look into that. It's an academic exercise now though - I've taken the view that even if the cache can be invalidated in FastCGI mode, it no longer feels reliable to use `require()` more than once (at least on hosting I have no control over).

Comment: I meant that when I got the notification for the comment, there was no actual link to the `phpinfo()` output so I figured you'd forgotten to post it. Good luck with your investigation, it's always fun in the most terrible way when a production server doesn't work as expected . *(Edit: just noticed what happened, by "above" I thought you meant the link was in the actual question, not a comment. Sorry!)*

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem with a config file, the only valid solution for now is to change the name of the config file with each modification:

1 - load config file

```
// get the config file name
$config_file=glob('config/config*.php'))[0] ?? null;

// load the settings
if($config_file) $settings=require_once($config_file);
```

2 - save the config file when needed

```
...

$data=['var'=>'value','other-var'=>'other value'];
$vars=var_export($data, TRUE);

// new file name
$file_name='config/config-'.time().'.php';
file_put_contents($file_name,"<?php\n return $vars;");

// delete old config file
if($config_file) @unlink($config_file);
```

Comment: Ah, cloning the file is a clever idea - it would invalidate whatever the opcache thinks it knows about the file. What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: 8 but it should work with earlier version